# What happens when NMinimize constraints are unsolvable

Tags: mathematical-optimization, constraint

I have an algebraic function in many variables which outputs a vector $v$.

The coefficients of the vector are high degree polynomials in many variables.

I want to maximize $\;v[[1]] /Norm[v]\;$ globally.

I thought I was being clever by writing the problem as maximizing $\;v[[1]]^2 / v.v\;$, constrained by $v[[1]] > 0$. However, I got the message that "NMaximize was unable to generate any initial points satisfying the inequality constraints".

My question is twofold:

1. Does NMaximize work better when the function doesn't use any square roots? That was my motivation for "being clever".
2. What if it can't find any positive $\;v[[1]]$? Will it still give an answer? Will the answer still maximize $\;v[[1]] /Norm[v]\;$ as was originally intended? Will it be correct? Ideally it should try to make $v[[1]]$  as close to positive as possible, and put the maximization as a secondary priority.

Edit:

This is the code specific to my problem:

```
vars = {v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6, v7, v8, v9, v10, v11, v12, v13, v14, 
  v15, v16, v17, v18, v20, v21, v22, v23, v25, v26, v28, v29, v30, 
  v32, v33, v36, v37, v38, v39, v41, v42, v44, v45, v48, v49, v52, 
  v53, v54, v55, v57, v58, v60, v61, v64, v65, v68, v69, v72, v73, 
  v74, v78, v79, v80, v81, v82, v83, v87, v88, v89, v93, v94, v95, 
  v99, v100, v108, v109, v110, v111, v112, v113, v117, v118, v119, 
  v123, v124, v125, v133, v134, v135, v143, v144, v145, v146, v147, 
  v148, v152, v153, v154, v158, v159, v160, v168, v169, v170, v178, 
  v179, v180}

exp ={...} (* exp is a vector of seven large polynomials in the above variables *)

funVer1p [in_] := 
 Module[{ nVec2, vals, vi},
  vi = exp[[in]]; nVec2 = exp.exp ; 
  vals = NMaximize[{vi/(nVec2^(1/2))}, vars]; 
  Normalize[(exp /. (vals[[2]]))] ]

funVer2p [in_] := 
 Module[{ nVec2, vals, vi}, vi = exp[[in]]; nVec2 = exp.exp; 
  vals = NMaximize[{(vi*vi)/nVec2, vi > 0}, vars]; 
  Normalize[(exp /. (vals[[2]]))] ]
```

My aim for now was to find how close I could get a normalized $exp$ vector in those parameters to the basis vectors or $\mathbb{R}^7$ , and what would the resulting vectors look like. That is, to calculate accurate $funVer1p \;[x],\; x\in \{1\cdots 7\}$.

Is $funVer2p\;$ more accurate/better for NMaximize than $funVer1p\;$? What about the cases where $vi$ cannot be made greater than $0$? What is the best approach to this problem?

Comment: I've ran a few examples and what should happen is that Mathematica keeps increasing the "tolerance" of the constraints. Based on this, the solution should be very slow to compute, but still correct. I'm still not sure whether eliminating the square root from the maximized function will help NMaximize work better.

Comment: Usually I try to avoid sqrt & Norm in minimization. Perhaps [coding the square](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/214861/how-to-make-minimize-with-sqrt-calculate-faster/214886#214886) might help.

Comment: @user3257842 It is not clear what you are asking. Add code.

Comment: I've added some code.