# What has Maximize been thinking about for so long?

Tags: mathematical-optimization

The command

```
Maximize[{Sqrt[2 x + 13] + (3 y + 5)^(1/3) + (8 z + 12)^(1/4), x + y + z == 3&&{x,y,z} >= 0}, {x, y, z}]
```

is running without any response on my comp for hours (as well as many other Mathematica commands).
This optimization problem is quite standard and easily solved
by Lagrange multipliers

```
L=Sqrt[2x+13]+(3y+5)^(1/3)+(8z+12)^(1/4)-t*(x+y+z-3);
```

For simplicity the conditions `{x,y,z}>=0` are not taken into account.

```
Reduce[D[L, x] == 0 && D[L, y] == 0 && D[L, z] == 0 && D[L, t] == 0, {x, y, z, t}, Reals]
```

> `x == 3/2 && y == 1 && z == 1/2 && t == 1/4`

The Hessian of `L` at this point is easily found by

```
M = {{D[L, x, x], D[L, x, y], D[L, x, z], D[L, x, t]}, {D[L, y, x], 
D[L, y, y], D[L, y, z], D[L, y, t]}, {D[L, z, x], D[L, z, y], 
D[L, z, z], D[L, z, t]}, {D[L, t, x], D[L, t, y], D[L, t, z], 
D[L, t, t]}} /. {x -> 3/2, y -> 1, z -> 1/2, t -> 1/4}
```

Next, the result of

```
Resolve[ForAll[{a,b,c,d}, ({a,b,c,d}.M).{a,b,c,d} <= 0], PositiveReals]
```

> `True`

states this is the maximum point (local and global) since the quadratic form `({a,b,c,d}.M).{a,b,c,d}` takes
nonpositive values on the positive reals.
Is there anoter way to symbolically solve this optimization problem?

Comment: BTW. the command of Maple `Student:-MultivariateCalculus:-LagrangeMultipliers(sqrt(2*x + 13) + (3*y + 5)^(1/3) + (8*z + 12)^(1/4), [x + y + z - 3], [x, y, z])` results in $\left[\frac{7}{2}-8^{\frac{1}{3}},1,-\frac{3}{2}+8^{\frac{1}{3}}\right]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a little help(substitute the rational powers,  see @MichaelE2 [coding the square](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/214861/how-to-make-minimize-with-sqrt-calculate-faster)  ) `Maximize` solves the problem:

```
Maximize[{wx + wy + wz ,x + y + z == 3 && {x, y, z} >= 0 && wx^2 == 2 x + 13 &&wy^3 == 3 y + 5 && wz^4 == 8z + 12}, {x, y, z, wx, wy, wz} ]
(*{8, {x -> 3/2, y -> 1, z -> 1/2, wx -> 4, wy -> 2, wz -> 2}}*)
```

Comment: UlrichNeumann (@ does not work.) : Thank you for the reference. +1 for the MichaelE2's answer. However, this is done by hand, not automatically.

Comment: You didn't ask for  "automated code generation", my answer refers to your question and shows a way to force `Maximize` on a real solution branch. Not more.

Comment: Your statement "shows a way to force Maximize on a real solution branch. Not more." is built on the sand: `Maximize[{Sqrt[2 x + 13] + Surd[3 y + 5, 3] + Surd[8 z + 12, 4],    x + y + z == 3 && {x, y, z} >= 0}, {x, y, z}]` is spinning too.