# Prove an inequality

Tags: equation-solving

With $\{a,b,c \} > 0$, prove that:

$\sqrt{\frac{16a}{b+c}+1}+\sqrt{\frac{16b}{a+c}+1}+\sqrt{\frac{16c}{a+b}+1}\ge 9$

Comment: See [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/250407/what-has-maximize-been-thinking-about-for-so-long) for a precedent.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork: the mix of math and Matematica notation $\{a,b,c\}>0$ does not make a good impression. It would be better `{a,b,c}>0`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What has Maximize been thinking about for so long?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/250407/what-has-maximize-been-thinking-about-for-so-long)

Comment: @user64494:  What notation did the poster teddy use for his equation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done as follows. We introduce additional  variables `x,y,z` to get rid of square roots.

```
Minimize[{x + y + z, x^2 == 16*a/(b + c) + 1 && y^2 == 16*b/(a + c) + 1 && 
z^2 == 16*c/(a + b) + 1 && a > 0 && b > 0 && c > 0 && x > 0 && 
y > 0 && z > 0}, {a, b, c, x, y, z}]
```

> `{9, {a -> 1, b -> 1, c -> 1, x -> 3, y -> 3, z -> 3}}`

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code. But just for fun I reverse engineered the logic of the question. So, I asked Mma to use global assumptions on `a,b,c` such that they are positive and to check if `given relation <9` will give me an empty set as it should. Weird thing is that Mma returned `True`. Could you have a look at the following bit of code? Seems like some tension(??) or my misunderstanding(??)

Comment: `$Assumptions = a > 0;
$Assumptions = b > 0;
$Assumptions = c > 0;` and then `Resolve[Exists[{a, b, c}, 
  Sqrt[(16 a)/(b + c) + 1] + Sqrt[(16 b)/(a + c) + 1] + 
    Sqrt[(16 c)/(a + b) + 1] < 9]]`

Comment: @kcr - Given a sequence of assignments to `$Assumptions` only the last assignment remains. You should use `$Assumptions = a > 0 && b > 0 && c > 0;` However, the result does not change.

Comment: @BobHanlon of course. How silly of me. Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

Numerically minimizing the expression

```
sol = N@NMinimize[{Sqrt[16 a/(b + c) + 1] + Sqrt[16 b/(a + c) + 1] + 
       Sqrt[16 c/(a + b) + 1], a > 0, b > 0, c > 0}, {a, b, c}, 
     WorkingPrecision -> 20,
     Method -> #] & /@ {"NelderMead", "DifferentialEvolution", 
   "SimulatedAnnealing", "RandomSearch"}

(* {{9., {a -> 2.56083, b -> 2.56083, c -> 2.56083}}, {9., {a -> 2.60199, 
   b -> 2.60199, c -> 2.60199}}, {9., {a -> 1.75712, b -> 1.75712, 
   c -> 1.75712}}, {9., {a -> 1.15048, b -> 1.15048, c -> 1.15048}}} *)
```

There is not a unique set of parameters for a minimum. However, as expected from the symmetry of the expression, `{a, b, c}` are all equal at **a** minimum. As seen above, the exact value of the minimum is

```
(Sqrt[16 a/(b + c) + 1] + Sqrt[16 b/(a + c) + 1] + 
   Sqrt[16 c/(a + b) + 1]) /. {b -> a, c -> a}

(* 9 *)
```